# How do I window removeEventListener using React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, removeeventlistener

In React Hooks documents it is shown how to removeEventListener during the component's cleanup phase. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

In my use case, I am trying to removeEventListener conditional to a state property of the functional component.

Here's an example where the component is never unmounted but the event listener should be removed:

```
function App () {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      if (collapsed) {
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp); // Not the same "handleKeyUp" :(
      } else {
        window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
      }
    },
    [collapsed]
  );

  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Escape':
        setCollapsed(true);
        break;
    }
  }

  return collapsed ? (
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick={()=>setCollapsed(false)}>Search</a>
  ) : (
    <span>
      <input placeholder="Search" autoFocus />&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:;">This</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:;">That</a>&nbsp;
      <input placeholder="Refinement" />
    </span>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')));
```

(Live sample at https://codepen.io/caqu/pen/xBeBMN)

The problem I see is that the `handleKeyUp` reference inside `removeEventListener` is changing every time the component renders. The function `handleKeyUp` needs a reference to `setCollapsed` so it must be enclosed by `App`. Moving `handleKeyUp` inside `useEffect` also seems to fire multiple times and lose the reference to the original `handleKeyUp`.

How can I conditionally window.removeEventListener using React Hooks without unmounting the component?

Comment: [How to (really) remove eventListeners in React](https://dev.to/marcostreng/how-to-really-remove-eventlisteners-in-react-3och)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can put the `handleKeyUp` function inside of the function given to `useEffect` ([which is the recommended way of doing it according to the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)) and only add the listener and return a cleanup function when `collapsed` is false.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (collapsed) {
    return;
  }

  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Escape":
        setCollapsed(true);
        break;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
}, [collapsed]);
```

Answer (score 72):

*Tholle's* answer may work, but it's bad practice to declare a function inside an `if`.

It makes it harder to follow when the function is declared and when it is not. Also it can lead to bugs because functions are hoisted up.

**There's a neater way to fix it:**

By wrapping your event handler with the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

```
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true)

const handleKeyUp = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      setCollapsed(true)
    }
}, [setCollapsed])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!collapsed) {
        window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)
    }

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)
}, [collapsed, handleKeyUp])
```

- `useCallback` has a dependency on `setCollapsed`. This makes sure `handleKeyUp` is not redefined when the component rerenders (which always happens when state changes)
- `useEffect` will conditionally add/remove the event listener, otherwise events will keep firing as long as the component is mounted.

> If you use a lot of event handlers in useEffect, there's a custom hook for that: https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/

Here's the question posters example updated with my solution: https://codepen.io/publicJorn/pen/eYzwENN

Comment: Very helpful!  It looks like you have extra closing curly braces in your `useEffect` though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks so much @publicJorn!

Comment: Why put `setCollapsed` as an argument to `useCallback`? Wouldn't it have been equivalent to just do `[]`?

Comment: What defines `event` in the example above? @publicJorn

Comment: @mowwwalker I updated the answer: explained why `setCollapsed` is there. 
@duhaime nice catch, fixed it and added link to working example.

Comment: @publicJorn My understanding is still that `setCollapsed` will never change so the `useEffect` will only run once, which is the same result as using `[]`

Comment: @mowwwalker in this specific case you are right. But placing `setCollapsed` in the "dependencies array" doesn't hurt either. And in my mind it's a best practise to always use the same patterns while coding. If the dependency WOULD change, you'd need it to reconstruct. Also see the note at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback 

This is why I always use eslint in my projects. It will warn when diverging from patterns you configure. It makes your code more predictable, easier to read and less prone to bugs.

Comment: @publicJorn I think code that has no functional effect should be a comment instead. When I'm reading code and see something that, based on my understanding, should be redundant or impossible, then it usually means I've misunderstood the code and should reread it. As a convention within a project I think it's fine since whoever works on the project can recognize the purpose, but for a public code snippet, I think it's misleading.

Comment: Assured me that I was on the right path. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually Tholle's answer is better, if possible. Prefer defining the callback within useEffect as long as it's possible. Then you don't need to bother with useCallback.
As Kent C Dodds suggests:
"If you must define a function for your effect to call, then do it inside the effect callback, not outside." https://epicreact.dev/myths-about-useeffect/