# useEffect not cleaning up after redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let me explain my problem I have been solving for all day.
I have a site with header which has of course by react-router links to other pages (home, projects, about, services, contact).
Have a Project component which is in '/projects' page and '/' (home) page.

I want to make a simple animation in Project.js component which depends if there is a 'vertical' or there is not this props. Clearly -> in '/projects' I want to do that animation on scroll - in other pages not.

Tried to do that by add if statement in useEffect but it's not working, get me an error 'cannot read property 'style' of null `` ref.current.style.transform = `translateY(${window.scrollY * -0.35}px)`; ``

This problem is showing up when I am changing pages in header i.eg. I am in '/projects' scrolling and is ok animation is working then go to '/' and when scroll got error I have showed above.

It is like my if statement is not working and when I am in '/' which Project component has props vertical={false} is making animation on scroll when I don't want to do that.

What I want? I want do make an animation using useEffect only if component has a props 'vertical' like this:

Project.js component code:

```
const Project = ({ image, className, vertical }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [isVertical, setIsVertical] = useState(vertical);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('component did mount');
        isVertical
            ? window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                  ref.current.style.transform = `translateY(${window.scrollY * -0.35}px)`;
              })
            : console.log('non-vertical');
    }, [isVertical]);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => console.log('unmount');
    });

    return <StyledProject image={image} className={className} vertical={vertical} ref={ref} />;
};
```

in home '/':

```
{images.map(({ image, id }) => (
    <Project key={id} image={image} />
 ))}
```

in '/projects':

```
 {images.map(({ image, id }) => (
    <StyledProject vertical image={image} key={id} />
 ))}
```

when I am in the path '/projects' and go to another path got error.
It is like after being in '/projects' it is saving all statements was but I want on every page reset useEffect and ref.current

Please help me, I can't go further since I don't fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that you are not removing event listener when component unmounts.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360736/how-do-i-window-removeeventlistener-using-react-useeffect) you can see an example how to do it.