# How to do fileReader.removeEventListener in React js in cleaup function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I have implemented a image previewer in React js
Here is the  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-previewer-7xgws)
. I want to removeEventListener when the component unmounts but I am not able to do it.
I tried doing it using useRef but was getting undefined  error and this warning

```
The ref value 'fileReader.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'fileReader.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a cleanup function in useEffect - which is the recommended way to handle itthis. Please refer: [How do I window removeEventListener using React useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360736/how-do-i-window-removeeventlistener-using-react-useeffect)

Comment: That doesn't work as I tried it already. It doesn't work because the object we are adding the event Listener to is not the same. Also, if you are sure of the answer you provided you can edit the codesandbox and share the link.