# React ref with scrollTo triggeres scroll event even though we add it after, and remove it

Tags: reactjs

I have a div with overflow and a scroll container. Upon switching the content in this container, I want to scroll it to the top (new contented loaded it), and I want to add an event listener that does things within the scroll, only after it's reached the top. I though achieving this with something simple like a ref and useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (divRef && divRef.current) {
      setCollapsed(false);
      divRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
      divRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollEvent);
  }
  return () => {
    divRef.current!.removeEventListener("scroll", onScrollEvent);
  };
}, [div, divRef]);
```

The `onScrollEvent` does some extra css styling to a legend within the div block, but should only be active once the user scrolls, hence the listener.

The problem I'm running into is the `scrollTo(0,0)` triggers the `onScrollEvent`, where it shouldn't. I have tried adding the listener as you can see AFTER the `scrollTo` & removing it.

`onScrollEvent` is just a simple check to enable state change or not:

```
 const onScrollEvent = () => {
    if (!userControlled && !collapsed) setCollapsed(true);
  };
```

The other odd thing that's happening to me, is I did eventually just use a solution with a timeout to check if we are at position `0 === divRef.current.scrollTo`, then added the event. But not I can no longer remove the event. In essense, it's always listening to the on `onScrollEvent` & within that event the state change of `userControlled` isn't detected.

Comment: Where is `onScrollEvent` defined?

Comment: Depending on where and how you defined `onScrollEvent`, the function identity might not be stable.

Comment: @Calvin updated with onScrollEvent

Comment: By initializing `onScrollEvent()` like this, it is assigned a new function on each render. What is `userControlled` used for? Is it only used by `onScrollEvent()`?

Comment: Here's a related post which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360736/how-do-i-window-removeeventlistener-using-react-useeffect