# Every New Keydown Is Rendered Squared Than Previous One

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, console.log

keyboard and console values

[image: 1]

Every next e.key is running two times more than previous one. After 8-9 characters it's rending 1000+ times per char.
Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="keyboard__wraper">
        <SystemPicker />
        <PressedDisplay list={list} setList={setList}/>
        <MediaKeys />
        <LayoutMain list={list} setList={setList}/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
const PressedDisplay = ({setList, list}) => {

  return (
    <>
        <div className="output-display">
          {list}
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default PressedDisplay
```

```
const LayoutMain = ({list, setList}) => {
    

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.key)
        setList([<p key={Math.random()}>{e.key}</p>, ...list])
    })        


  return (
    <Fragment>
        <div className="layout__container">
                <div className='layout-main-key esc'><p>ESC</p></div>
            .
            .
            .
```

I checked If There Is Code Duplication But It Doesn't Seem To Exist.
[A try with useEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjaXs.png).
Tried What I Know With Use Effect But Again Same

Comment: Every time you add an element to the list, all sub-components get rerenderd, so you should remove the listener on rerendering the element with useEffect hook, i think

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I window removeEventListener using React useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360736/how-do-i-window-removeeventlistener-using-react-useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `useEffect` hook wrong, I defined a function that will fire/execute upon `keydown` event, this fixed my code.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    function pressKeySon (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.key);
        setList([<p key={Math.random()}>{e.key}</p>, ...list])
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', pressKeySon)
    
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', pressKeySon);
    
}, [list])
```